# Why this code is exploitable?

Tags: c, security

Why this code is unsecured?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
       printf(argv[1]);
       printf("\n");
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why should we do your homework for you?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` will process its first parameter, looking for things like `%d` and `%s`.

Based on those values, it will get more data from the stack and print it out.

So if someone called your program:

```
a.out "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d"
```

They could view a section of your computer's callstack.

If they got even more creative with the format specifier, maybe they could dump something important, like a credit-card number or a password.

Comment: with `%n` you can even write anywhere in memory

Comment: Yes that what I thought but it print only the % because it prints   argv[1], that's it..

Comment: This is relatively benign; `%n` can cause active damage (e.g. modify the control flow).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: My example was meant to be benign and easy to understand.  Most people don't know %n.  Everyone knows %d.  I did mention "If they got even more creative...."

Comment: @0x90 seems to suggests that it'd literally print %d.  That is wrong.  Consider the very basic `printf("Hello %s", "World");`.  Note that printf will process the first parameter, looking for specifiers like %s that tell it what to do next.

Comment: @abelenky so calling `a.out " %s"` will print all the stack?

Comment: %s will cause printf to print until it encounters an null-terminator ('\0'), which marks the end of a string in C.   Typically, this isn't very long, but theoretically, there may not be an null-terminator for a very long stretch of memory.

Comment: @0x90, @ouah: You wouldn't use `%n` just on its own, but rather with something like `"%500d%1024x%10000x%40000s%n"` - to make the `printf()` eat args on the stack till the position where it encounters a "usable" pointer, and control the amount of data written using the format field width adjusters. That way you'll get a known value that `printf()` will put into the pointer specified by the arg to `%n`.

Comment: @FrankH. can you write it more specifically in an answer though?

Comment: @0x90: I've written you a small example, see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider what the first argument of `printf` controls (hint: `printf` doesn't just read its input arguments).

Answer (score 4):

Look at what is a format string vulnerability:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Answer (score 1):

You can find a explanation here.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Format_String

Answer (score 1):

Since poster asked for an example what `%n` does:

The way a `printf` format string can *change* memory is by using the `%n` option; a specific value to be written can be obtained by using format-width specifiers "wisely". As a test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *q = (int *)argv[0];
    printf("%1$300000d%5$n",
        123,         // %1 - 1st param (formatted as '300000d')
        0,           // %2 - 2nd param (unused)
        0,           // %3 - 3rd param (unused)
        0,           // %4 - 4th param (unused)
        argv[0]);    // %5 - 5th param (written to via 'n')

    printf("\nNow *q == %d\n", *q);

    return 0;
}
```

If you run this and look a the last line of output, it'll print `Now *q == 300000` (tested on Linux).

I'm using the rather-unknown *positional format syntax* (`%`<pos>`$`<fmt>) for `printf()` here in order to show how one can skip arguments to choose which one to modify without needing to use any of the "noninteresting" ones.

I'll leave it to the readers experiments to figure out what `printf()` treats as "arguments" for a call like `printf(argv[1])`. The answer to that depends on the [*calling conventions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calling-convention) (or related, the [*ABI*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abi) for your system), and is different for 32/64bit Windows/Linux/MacOSX etc.